# Nodejs multiple client handling

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have already setup a standard nodejs server and now i have the problem if one client send a request via socket.io and every client reacts to it but this is wrong i want that only the client who sends the request should react.

on client side:

```
function show(){
                socket.emit('show')
            }
```

on server side:

```
    socket.on('show', function(){
       io.emit('request', 'clear');    //clear a table on the website
       db.each("SELECT tableRow1, tableRow2, tableRow3 FROM table, 
       function(err, row){
          io.emit('new', row.tableRow1, row.tableRow2, row.tableRow3)
       });
     });
```

and the reaction on the client side is:

```
    socket.on('new', function(tableRow1, tableRow2, tableRow3){
       var myString = ' <input id="id1" type="checkbox" name="boxes"><label for="id1" id="labelID" onclick="Click(this)">'tableRow1'</label>'
       $('#tableID').append($('<tr>')
       .append($("<td>"+myString+'<td/>'+"<td>tableRow2</td>"+"<td>"TableRow3"</td>")).append($('<tr/>')));
  });
```

and now the problem is then 1 client presses the button to load data form the database all clients react to it and are getting the data from the server.

Comment: Could you share the code you're currently trying this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use socket.emit from server side. 
Check out this socket.io cheatsheet, https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/3f257d0bb813e2c8c476

client-side example

```
// send to server
socket.emit('retrieve users')
// register callback
socket.on('retrieve users', doSomething)
```

server-side example

```
// sending to sender-client only
socket.on('retrieve users', () => socket.emit('retrieve users', users))
```

Comment: it didnt work it cruses an error "cant read property of undefind emit"

Comment: pass socket object to your show function in client-side script and change io.emit('new') to socket.emit('new')